# Firebase Database connection was forcefully killed by the server: Different region #flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I am building the app with flutter and integrating the firebase. In the start, my app works completely fine but after some time a faced this problem firebase forcefully kill the connection between the app and the server.

W/PersistentConnection( 4812): pc_0 - Firebase Database connection was forcefully killed by the server. Will not attempt reconnect. Reason: Database lives in a different region. Please change your database URL to https://multiapp-f0e1e-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69006147/is-there-a-way-to-fix-the-error-will-not-attempt-reconnect-reason-database-li

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This happens because, when you created your project at that time the Realtime Database was not enabled, that's why the `google-services.json` file don't contain the `url` to our Realtime Database.

I was also faced with a same problem, here's what I did.

We can also download an updated `google-services.json` file. But I manually added the url.

from this:

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "xxx4071207xxx",
    "project_id": "xxxantonixxx",
    "storage_bucket": "xxxantonixxx.appspot.com"
  },
```

to this:

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "xxx4071207xxx",
    "firebase_url": " https://multiapp-f0e1e-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app",
    "project_id": "xxxantonixxx",
    "storage_bucket": "xxxantonixxx.appspot.com"
  },
```

### You'll get your database Url from here:

[image]

### But wait... it still might not work.

If you make changes to the `google-services.json` file. And recompile the app from start, still the changes **DONOT** take place immediately.

In my case, even if I **deleted** the `google-services.json` file and recompile the app again, it was working similar to before deleting.

### Solution:##

So, in that case, we'll have to **delete the `build` and `.dart_tool` folder** in our project folder,

Or  run `flutter clean` in terminal

and then **recompile the app again from start.**

I came to know about this after I wasted my 2 whole days, working in some other direction. That's why I had to share it, so that it doesn't happen to anybody else.

Comment: Don't forget to `flutter pub get` after you cleaned dart_tools.

Comment: Silly me, I downloaded google-services.json before enabling the Realtime Database!

Answer (score 1):

When you create a real-time database for the first time, DATABASE_URL is added to your config file (GoogleService-Info.plist & google-services.json) file on the server-side. You may be getting an error because the (GoogleService-Info.plist & google-services.json) is outdated and does not contain DATABASE_URL. You can download your updated (GoogleService-Info.plist & google-services.json) file from your Project Settings and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Even after @Madhav's(accepted answer) solution didn't work, try creating a fresh project and follow the steps mentioned in accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do like the first comment said after that just run the command flutter clean and build again and everything should work just fine!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30945302)

Answer (score 0):

make sure to delete build  and .dart_tool folders, then it works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is ALSO the error message if you are silly like me and are trying to connect to **Google Girebase Database** instead of what I actually had set up which is **Google Firestore**.

```
// Bad:
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("users/123");


// Good
var db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

// (or vice versa)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FirebaseDatabase("your database URL").reference()
```

// Or

```
FirebaseDatabase(databaseURL: "your database URL").reference()
```

instead of

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference()
```

Only for flutter users. It is happening because your database is outSide US servers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, howewer manually changing the `google-services.json`

and running `flutter clean` or deleting the files didnt fix it for me.

So i just reran flutterfire configure ([Flutterfire Dokumentation on installing and getting started](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?hl=de&platform=ios)

And this worked just fine.