# The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null', when fetching data from firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-animation

```
  DatabaseReference databaseRef= FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child("collecton-name");
```

I am to display data from firebase, and so when I fetch information like below, I get this error.

```
FirebaseAnimatedList(
            query:databaseRef,
            itemBuilder:(BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
            Animation<double>animation, int index){
              var x=snapshot.value['title'];
              print(x);
        return ListTile(
      subtitle: Text(snapshot.value['title']),
      title:Text(snapshot.value['subtitle'])
      );
      },
        ),
```

This is the error for the title, subtitle, and the variable.

```
The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
```

Comment: Can you include what are you getting on print

Comment: This is the error I get on print too.

Comment: try to print `snapshot.value`

Comment: W/PersistentConnection(14441): pc_0 - Firebase Database connection was forcefully killed by the server. Will not attempt reconnect. Reason: Firebase error. Please ensure that you spelled the name of your Firebase correctly

Comment: This is the error, as for reference, I passed the collection-name

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69060872/10157127) solve your issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246831/discussion-between-pratishtha-s-and-yeasin-sheikh).