# Firebase database connection was killed but information is going to a database just dunno what one Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've added Firebase into my Android Studio however I am getting an error:

> W/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Firebase Database connection was forcefully killed by the server. Will not attempt to reconnect. Reason: The database lives in a different region. Please change your database URL to https://destination-e6a01-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app"

I changed the region but nothing is happening
In my app I have this in my java code:

```
// Initialize Firebase in your app
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);

        // Create a reference to your Firebase Realtime Database instance using the URL
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://Destination.firebaseio.com/");
        Log.d("TAG", "Database URL: " + database.getReference().toString());


        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("destination-e6a01-default-rtdb");

        Spinner categorySpinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner_categories);
        String category = categorySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

        double latitude = 52.519345;
        double longitude = -6.610428;

        VanCameraLocations speedvancameralocations = new VanCameraLocations(latitude, longitude, category);

        myRef.push().setValue(speedvancameralocations);
```

I tried using this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69060872/firebase-database-connection-was-forcefully-killed-by-the-server-different-regi) however the answer for this question didn't work for me. My logcat is saying some information was uploaded to a database but the database I am using when I go look at my database online it doesn't show my database can anyone help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the following error message:

> Firebase Database connection was forcefully killed by the server. Will not attempt to reconnect. Reason: The database lives in a different region.

Because you're passing to the [getInstance()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase#getInstance(java.lang.String)) method, the wrong URL:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://Destination.firebaseio.com/");
```

The URL of your project is not:

```
https://Destination.firebaseio.com/
```

But:

```
https://destination-e6a01-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app
```

So to solve this, please change the `database` declaration to:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://destination-e6a01-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app");
```

Besides that, please remove the following line of code:

```
//DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("destination-e6a01-default-rtdb");
```

Because the database URL should be passed to the `getInstance()` method and not the `getReference()` method. One more thing to mention is that when you pass an URL, you have to pass with the `https://` not without it.