# i am getting error when using firebase realtime database in flutter application

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-dependencies, mobile-application

i am not able to send data in firebase realtime database in flutter application.

getting this error :-

Firebase Database connection was forcefully killed by the server. Will not attempt reconnect. Reason: Database lives in a different region. Please change your database URL to https://jonk-amit-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app

Answer (score 0):

This usually means that you are either missing a database URL in your configuration or have a wrong database URL in your configuration. Either way, the solution is to redownload or regenerate the configuration - usually in the same was as you got/generated it the first time around.

We've covered this error quite a few times before, so I recommend checking out:

- [Firebase Realtime Database connection killed: Different Region](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68806876/firebase-realtime-database-connection-killed-different-region)
- [Why is the Firebase Realtime Database's data appearing as null in the console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68025986/why-is-the-firebase-realtime-databases-data-appearing-as-null-in-the-console)
- [Firebase Database connection was forcefully killed by the server: Different region #flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69060872/firebase-database-connection-was-forcefully-killed-by-the-server-different-regi)

Answer (score 0):

i updated google-service.json file , now this is working perfectly